# ms access create report with two tables

Tags: ms-access

I am needing to create a report between two tables. One table has ID, FirstName, LastName. The seconded table has NoteID, ID and Notes. There is a one to many relationship. Each person can have many notes. What I would like to do is fill a listbox or textbox with the notes that belong to that person.

On that note, how can I create a report that will display somewhat as the following:

---

```
First Name: Jeff    Last Name: Smith
Notes:
 This is note 1 for Jeff Smith
 This is note 2 for Jeff Smith
 This is note 3 for Jeff Smith
 This is note 4 for Jeff Smith
```

---

```
First Name: Kim    Last Name: Yung
Notes:
  This is note 1 for Kim Yung
  This is note 2 for Kim Yung
```

---

Thank you for any thing on this to lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - so I made a query to use as the Record Source for the Report.

```
SELECT People.ID, 
       People.FirstName, 
       People.LastName, 
       Notes.NOTES
FROM People INNER JOIN Notes 
ON People.ID = Notes.ID;
```

I clicked report design, set this query as the Record Source for the report.
I added a **GROUPING** on `ID` (this is to separate each person's `Notes`).

This created an **ID HEADER**, which is where you put `FirstName`, `LastName`, and your `Notes` label.

In the Detail section, you put the `NOTES` field from your query.

[image]

### Output

---

[image]

If you have any other questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **Subreport**. A Report that will have another report in it. This works in a similar way to a Main Form and Sub Form. More information is available on the MS Office website : https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-and-use-subreports-816f987a-4615-4058-8f20-ce817093bb33